# How to trigger mutate (SWR) in Next component when the prop or state is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, swr

I have this annoying problem. I have history list with pagination. For every page I fetch the data with `useSWR`. The pagination works fine, but when I add a new entry in history list (and trigger the mutate) I got new history data only on the current page. When I go page up or page down, the `useSWR` use the cached data for every other page in history list. In ReactQuery there is an option to disable caching, but it does not exist in new `useSWR`.

So my question is, can I do `mutate(key)` on prop or state update? Or if not, can I disable caching or force `useSWR` on every prop or state change?

Comment: When ever you call your add action you could probably use `useSWRConfig()` to grab the cache, then find all the keys you want to invalidate and remove them.